# Edit Data Table Value adds extra row

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

```
<p:column headerText="Cancel" width="60">    
  <p:commandLink actionListener="#{userLeaveBean.cancelForLeave}" title="Cancel Request" process="@this" update="leaveDataTable" disabled="false">
    <h:graphicImage url="resources/images/cancel.gif"/>
        <f:attribute name="userId" value="#{employee.name}"/>
        <f:attribute name="leaveId" value="#{leaveDetails.strLeaveId}"/>
</p:commandLink></p:column>
```

Hi I have written this code to modify a row value of a data table. The method that invoked named 'cancelForLeave' modifies the detail of the row value of the data table.The method is as follows:

```
public void cancelForLeave(ActionEvent actionEvent){

    String userId = (String)actionEvent.getComponent().getAttributes().get("userId");
    String leaveId = (String)actionEvent.getComponent().getAttributes().get("leaveId");
    int currentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    ConnectLdap connectLdap = new ConnectLdap();
    UserTotalLeaveInfoBean userTotalLeaveInfoBean = connectLdap.getUserLeaveBean(""+currentYear, userId);

    if(userTotalLeaveInfoBean != null){

        UserGeneralLeaveDetailsBean[] userGeneralLeaveDetailsBean = userTotalLeaveInfoBean.getArrUserGeneralLeaveDetailsBean();
        if(userGeneralLeaveDetailsBean != null){
            for(int i=0;i<userGeneralLeaveDetailsBean.length;i++){

                String beanLeaveId = userGeneralLeaveDetailsBean[i].getStrLeaveId();
                if(leaveId.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(beanLeaveId)){

                    if(userGeneralLeaveDetailsBean[i].getStrLeaveStatus().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(LeaveStatus.LVST_APPLIED)){
                        userGeneralLeaveDetailsBean[i].setStrLeaveStatus(LeaveStatus.LVST_CANCELED);
                    }if(userGeneralLeaveDetailsBean[i].getStrLeaveStatus().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(LeaveStatus.LVST_APPROVED)){
                        userGeneralLeaveDetailsBean[i].setStrLeaveStatus(LeaveStatus.LVST_CANCELREQ);
                    }
                    userTotalLeaveInfoBean.setArrUserGeneralLeaveDetailsBean(userGeneralLeaveDetailsBean);
                    connectLdap.addAppliedLeaveInLdap(userTotalLeaveInfoBean, ""+currentYear, userId);
                    leaveDetails.add(userGeneralLeaveDetailsBean[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

private List<UserGeneralLeaveDetailsBean> leaveDetails;
//Getter and Setter
```

Now the problem is that, When I click on the image button it modifies the value for the row, but adds an extra row in the data table with the modified value. But when I Logout and then Again login,it shows there is no extra row, and the row I attempted to modify shows nicesly with the modified value.

what should be done to prevent the extra row addition at run time, while attempting for the value change of the data table row?Please Help!!

I get the following Log Details: If I put a Log in the page:

`Monday, June 03, 2013 3:59:55 PM : Initiating ajax request.
Monday, June 03, 2013 3:59:55 PM : Form to post applyLeaveForm.
Monday, June 03, 2013 3:59:55 PM : URL to post /DemoApplication/applyLeave.xhtml.
Monday, June 03, 2013 3:59:55 PM : Post Data:javax.faces.partial.ajax=true&javax.faces.source=applyLeaveForm%3AleaveDataTable%3A0%3Aj_idt90&javax.faces.partial.execute=applyLeaveForm%3AleaveDataTable%3A0%3Aj_idt90&javax.faces.partial.render=applyLeaveForm%3AleaveDataTable&applyLeaveForm%3AleaveDataTable%3A0%3Aj_idt90=applyLeaveForm%3AleaveDataTable%3A0%3Aj_idt90&applyLeaveForm=applyLeaveForm&applyLeaveForm%3AfromDate_input=&applyLeaveForm%3AtoDate_input=&applyLeaveForm%3Aj_idt59=morning&applyLeaveForm%3Aj_idt60=endofday&applyLeaveForm%3AleaveDataTable%3A0%3AeditFrom_input=03-Jun-2013&applyLeaveForm%3AleaveDataTable%3A0%3Aj_idt68=morning&applyLeaveForm%3AleaveDataTable%3A0%3AeditTo_input=04-Jun-2013&applyLeaveForm%3AleaveDataTable%3A0%3Aj_idt72=endofday&javax.faces.ViewState=-3803632482959899224%3A-5634910090194656061
Monday, June 03, 2013 3:59:55 PM : Response received succesfully.
Monday, June 03, 2013 3:59:56 PM : DOM is updated.
Monday, June 03, 2013 3:59:56 PM : Response completed.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add the modified item back to your list :

```
leaveDetails.add(userGeneralLeaveDetailsBean[i]);
```

You must **remove** this line and it should fix your problem. You are updating your source the line just before, and the add only apply in the current view, that's why refreshing get the right data.

Also your bean must be at least in `@ViewScoped` or `@SessionScoped`.